# compile golang package in yocto

Tags: go, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to write a yocto recipe to compile https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx package, which is written on Golang. And no matter what, I can't get the package to build the binary. I have little to no experience with Go.

So far, I have managed to get the recipe to clone proper version from git and with correct LIC_FILES_CHKSUM but I am struggling to get it to actually generate a binary from the source.

```
SUMMARY = "mediamtx RTSP server"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx"
SECTION = "multimedia"
LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit goarch pkgconfig

#GO_IMPORT = "github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=77fd2623bd5398430be5ce60489c2e81"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx;branch=main"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRCREV = "21756a4d54152872cda48469861147ee652df922"

FILES_${PN} += "${GOBIN_FINAL}/*"


DEPENDS += "\
        go \
        python \
"

do_install_append() {
    cp ${D}${bindir}/mediamtx ${D}${bindir}/${BPN}
}
```

if I remove `do_install_append` then the recipe builds successfully but it doesn't compile the code to create a binary - which seems obvious to me as there is no `do_compile` section. I can't seem to find any information which tells me how to get it to compile.

It'd be great if someone is able to provide me a yocto recipe for this package, if not then any kind of help/direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The yocto manual refers to inheriting `go` class. It seems that it already inherits `goarch`. As a first step uncomment the `GO_IMPORT` line, and inherit `go` instead of `goarch`

Comment: thanks @skandigraun, after these change yocto does somehow reach the `do_compile` method but it fails for some dependencies.

`src/github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx/internal/conf/stringsize.go:6:2: cannot find package "code.cloudfoundry.org/bytefmt"` etc

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to find/create separate recipes for these dependencies, and add them to `DEPENDS`. Yocto doesn't allow network access after the fetch step.

Comment: haha okay, I'll try that. It has 46 dependencies! that seems like ridiculous amount of effort for one binary :D. thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Well, maybe there is an easier trick that I'm not aware of... don't work an awful lot with go recipes.

Comment: [Please remove all the line numbers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that same problem, this worked for me.

```
SUMMARY = "MediaMTX / rtsp-simple-server is a ready-to-use and zero-dependency server and proxy that allows users to publish, read and proxy live video and audio streams."
GO_IMPORT = "github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx"
HOMEPAGE = "https://${GO_IMPORT}"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://src/${GO_IMPORT}/LICENSE;md5=77fd2623bd5398430be5ce60489c2e81"

SRC_URI = "git://${GO_IMPORT};branch=main;protocol=https"
SRCREV = "65f617aa7c326f491c4f4f4a4d52beea3bd6abc7"

GO_INSTALL = "${GO_IMPORT}"
do_compile[network] = "1"

# build executable instead of shared object
GO_LINKSHARED = ""
GOBUILDFLAGS:remove = "-buildmode=pie"

inherit go-mod

FILES:${PN} += "/usr/local/bin"
```

I'm using Yocto's kirkstone release.

Comment: Legend! This worked for me. I am using Yocto Kirkstone as well. Thanks :)